# time series forecasting - ljung-box test - degrees of freedom to subtract when working with breaks

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I'm working on a differentiated seasonal time series with 2 breaks and non-zero mean. So, besides the constant i've got 2 dummies for breaks correction.

Question: when performing LB test, if my model is (2,1,1)(1,0,1) should i consider only p+q+P+Q coefs for subtracting degrees of freedom (meaning -5 degrees) or should i include all the constants (meaning -8 degrees)?

Comment: use all the  implied coefficients  .. less.8 in your case

Comment: @IrishStat alright. But i just read that LB test does not perform well for ARIMAX model so i'm switching to BG test. Since bgtest() doesn't have a fitfd argument, should i subtract -8 from lag argument?

Comment: OK .............